# OpenCV Java, Read HSV Value of the center pixel

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I seem to be getting more than 3 values from my code below, wernt there  only suppose to be 3 values, H, S and V? What have i done wrong?

**Code:**

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);

            int width= bitmap.getWidth();
            int height=bitmap.getHeight();

            int centerX=width/2;
            int centerY=height/2;
            srcMat = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, srcMat);
            //Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, matHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
            srcMat.convertTo(srcMat, CvType.CV_64FC3); //http://answers.opencv.org/question/14961/using-get-and-put-to-access-pixel-values-in-java/
            int size = (int) (srcMat.total() * srcMat.channels());
            Mat matHSV = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, matHSV);
            double[] data = new double[size];

            srcMat.get(centerX, centerY, data);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                data[i] = (data[i] / 2);  // no more casting required.
                Log.e("HSV Values:", String.valueOf(data[i]));
            }



        }
```

**Output:**

I get a lot of values printed using Log.e, even though I'm technically suppose to only get 3 values, H, S & V.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing HSV values.

Your `data` variable is an array of doubles with the number of cells equal to the number of pixels of the original image multiplied by the number of channels, because you've calculated the value of the `size` variable incorrectly. You are iterating through that array and printing its every element in each iteration, so you are printing `channels * width * height` values.

If you want to get a HSV value of a single pixel in the center, just do this:

```
double[] data = srcMat.get(centerX, centerY);
```

Now the array contains the 3 values you want.

Alternatively, probably you wanted to do this:

```
 int size = (int) (srcMat.channels());
```

Instead of this:

```
int size = (int) (srcMat.total() * srcMat.channels());
```